# How can I have multiple controllers with same name but in different folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have 2 controllers that have the same name but one of them is in a subfolder called "v2", when I run the application I get this error

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Article'
```

[image]

I tried to add the namespace in my WebApiConfig.cs but that does not help

```
        // Api V2 Route
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiV2",
            routeTemplate: "api/v2/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: In new defination `new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },` here you should write somethng like `new { controller = "Your another controller", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },`

Comment: Looks like you want to version your API. You could check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/visual-studio-toolbox/versioning-aspnet-core-services

Comment: On the other hand you can use `routes.MapRoute` twice on your `startup.cs`

Comment: In `routeconfig.cs` you could define two `routes.MapRoute` for the second route definition. Or use [API versioning](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-api-versioning/)

Comment: I tried to add a route in WebApiConfig as shown above and also tried to add a route in RouteConfig.cs with new { controller = "Your another controller", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } but still no success.....

Comment: Try to remove the bin folder and then recompile again.

Comment: Sorry, to clear the bin folder and recompile does not help. It compile but I still get the error when trying the api in postman

Comment: @MTplus - To me it looks like you should specify where the controllers are placed, default is the Controllers folder and you have ApiControllers. How are the controllers decorated?